# Finding username of the last post in mysql table joining 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I know I am doing this qry wrong - its taking over 10secs for the results to come back w/ only 3000 rows of data...
I have 3 tables: 
**users**
id
username

```
DATA:
1|tom
2|dick
3|harry
```

**posts**
id
id_users

```
DATA:
1|1
2|1
3|1
4|2
5|2
6|3
```

**cronjobs**
id
id_post
id_wall

```
DATA:   id|id_post|id_wall
1|1|1
2|1|2
3|1|3
4|1|4
5|1|5
6|2|5
7|4|3
8|6|3
9|4|4
```

A user will make a post
That post will be put on one or more walls and stored in the **cronjobs** table.
The id on **cronjobs** is auto increment.
I need to get the username and last post on each wall.
In the above example

Dick was the last person to post on wall 4 with post 4
Harry was the last person to post on wall 3 with post 6
Tom was the last person to post on wall 5 with post 2
Tom was the last person to post on wall 2 with post 1
Tom was the last person to post on wall 1 with post 1

Here is the qry im currently using, I know using the IN clause with the select inside it, is killing this....

```
SELECT 
  c.id,
  c.id_post,
  c.id_wall AS id_wall,
  p.id_users AS user_id,
  u.NAME AS username 
FROM
  cronjobs c,
  posts p,
  users u 
WHERE c.id IN 
  (SELECT MAX(id) 
  FROM
    cronjobs 
  GROUP BY id_wall) 
  AND c.id_post = p.id 
  AND p.id_users = u.id 
ORDER BY c.id
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
  c.id,
  c.id_post,
  c.id_wall AS id_wall,
  p.id_users AS user_id,
  u.NAME AS username 
FROM
  cronjobs c,
  posts p,
  users u ,
  (SELECT MAX(id) as id 
  FROM
    cronjobs 
  GROUP BY id_wall) table_id
  where c.id_post = p.id 
  AND p.id_users = u.id 
and table_id.id  =c.id
ORDER BY c.id
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks so much!
The below qry works as well, and execution time were the same for both, this one was first so Im marking it as the answer.
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use join instead of a subquery in `where` clause, subquery in `join` part will be executed once while subquery in `where` clause will be executed for all the resultant rows this query will perform much better than yours, also index your columns that appears in `on()` part

```
SELECT 
  c.id,
  c.id_post,
  c.id_wall AS id_wall,
  p.id_users AS user_id,
  u.username AS username 
FROM
  cronjobs c
  join (SELECT  MAX(id) id ,id_wall
      FROM cronjobs 
      GROUP BY id_wall) c1 on c.id = c1.id and c.id_wall = c1.id_wall
  join posts p on c.id_post = p.id 
  join users u on p.id_users = u.id 
ORDER BY c.id
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c68f8/3)

Comment: and if the `on` clause contains multiple criteria, consider a composite index, not one index per field

Comment: @pala_ yup a composite index is needed same for where clause if where clause criteria includes multiple columns